# cakephp 3 CsvView plugin utf-8 support(FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview)

Tags: csv, cakephp-3.0

I use **FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview** plugin for cakephp3 to create csv export file

```
$data=[ ['سلام','سلام','35'],
        ['سلام','سلام','40']];

$_header = ['title','subject','number'];  
$_serialize = 'data';        
$_extension = 'mbstring';
$_dataEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$_csvEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$this->response->download( 'output' . '.csv');
$this->viewBuilder()->className('CsvView.Csv');     
$this->set(compact(`data`, `_header`,`_serialize`, `_extension`, `_dataEncoding`, `_csvEncoding`));
```

---

and output:

[image: cakephp-csvview]

title   subject number

```
Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…    Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…    35

Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…    Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù…    40
```

Comment: How is it that the first column in your $data array is ending up in the third column of the spreadsheet? Any chance that the code you're looking at isn't actually the code that's running?

Comment: the code is actually but data isn't actually.i want to show difficult in utf-8 in this code

Answer (score 1):

_bom: false

_bom: true

if _bom : true remove the bom character and in csv file view utf8 character

```
$_csvEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$_newline = "\r\n";
$_eol = "\r\n";
$_bom = true;


$this->set(compact(`data`, `_header`,`_serialize`, `_extension`, `_dataEncoding`, `_csvEncoding`, '_newline', '_eol', '_bom'));
```

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean? And are you sure you want to use so much backticks in PHP code?